# How to write HTML inside Razor Condition in MVC View.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new with C# since i have goal to check condition in view if session set display login and register links else display profile

```
@if (Session["reguseremail"] == null)
{
    @<a class="btn btn-login" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLoginModal();">Log in</a>/
    @<a class="btn btn-register" data-toggle="modal" href="@Url.Action("register", "frontend")">Register</a>
}
@else
{
   @<a class="btn btn-profile" data-toggle="modal" href="@Url.Action("profile", "frontend")">Profile</a>
{
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: First glance looks like you have _way_ too many `@`

Comment: @Jimenemex Getting @ parse error  which not letting my application to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` is not needed in the lines inside the if, try using this instead

```
@if (Session["reguseremail"] == null) 
{
   <a class="btn btn-login" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLoginModal();">Log in</a>
   <a class="btn btn-register" data-toggle="modal" href="@Url.Action("register", "frontend")">Register</a> } 
else 
{
   <a class="btn btn-profile" data-toggle="modal" href="@Url.Action("profile", "frontend")">Profile</a> 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alot it worked. strange why it was not when i was did not used @ on every html line.

Comment: The @ is used as compiler directive, so you can just use them anywhere. Pls mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Sure i could do early but it was not letting me before 6 minutes. Thanks for remove my miss concept about razor syntax,